# Getting javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate as null in HttpsFilter class after karaf stepup to 4.4.3

Tags: java, rest, web, apache-karaf

Getting "javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate" as null in "HttpsFilter" class after Karaf step-up to 4.4.3

```java
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;

public class HttpsFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext) {
        if (isSecure) {
            X509Certificate[] x509Certificate = (X509Certificate[]) containerRequestContext.getProperty("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");
            --------------------
        }
    }
}
```

After upgrading Karaf to 4.4.3, the "javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate" is returning as null within the "HttpsFilter" class, although it was working correctly before. Any ideas on how to resolve this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: I've created https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.web/issues/1868 because this may be a problem after the refactoring. I'll check after the weekend.

Comment: Ok Thanks for raising the bug in pax web, pls reply once you checked.

Comment: Not yet. Give me some time please.

Comment: I just checked that this attribute is present in Pax Web 8 used in Karaf 4.4.3. You'd have to provide more details about how did you configure Karaf and CXF (?) here. Where do you use HttpsFilter? Please add details to https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.web/issues/1868

Comment: @GrzegorzGrzybek could you pls let me know when does this attribute "Javax.servlet.request.X509certificate" get populated in containerrequestcontext before it comes to filter method.

Comment: It depends on which Pax Web runtime you use (Jetty? Tomcat? Undertow?) If (default in Karaf 4.4) it's Jetty, the attribute is "virtual": https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.51.v20230217/jetty-server/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/server/SecureRequestCustomizer.java#L355

Comment: Any idea on how does containerrequestcontext  gets built with Javax.servlet.request.X509certificate before filter method?

Comment: we were using Jetty , pax web 8.0.15 and karaf 4.4.3, also we use pax web whiteboard feature. –

Comment: we get only below property names if i do getPropertyNames from containerrequstcontext object    " [org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.TracingLogger, javax.servlet.request.key_size, org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.request.ssl_session, javax.servlet.request.cipher_suite, javax.servlet.request.ssl_session_id]"  pls advise on this

Comment: do you have client certificate requirement turned on? (show me `etc/org.ops4j.pax.web.cfg`)

Comment: we have below props set in pax web cfg,  org.ops4j.pax.web.config.file=${karaf.etc}/jetty.xml
org.osgi.service.http.port=${karaf.web.port}
org.osgi.service.http.enabled=true
org.osgi.service.http.secure.enabled=true
org.osgi.service.http.secure.enabled.protocols=TLSv1.2
org.osgi.service.http.port.secure=${karaf.web.secure.port}
org.ops4j.pax.web.ssl.ciphersuites.included=<some value>
org.ops4j.pax.web.ssl.clientauthwanted=true
org.ops4j.pax.web.ssl.clientauthneeded=true

Comment: @GrzegorzGrzybek pls help on this.

Comment: @GrzegorzGrzybek  After enabled debug logs, i saw we were getting  below from jettyAwareLogger,
->SslConnection@b4b9f98{NOT_HANDSHAKING,eio=-1/-1,di=-1,fill=IDLE,flush=IDLE}
Any idea on this? Any property we need to add to solve this?

Comment: SO comments are not the best way to solve this issue. Please add more details (like logs and configs) to https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.web/issues/1868. Seeing the bundles you have installed would also help (in Karaf: `la -l`)

Comment: But the solution may be quicker ;) Use `org.ops4j.pax.web.ssl.clientauth.needed` instead of `org.ops4j.pax.web.ssl.clientauthneeded`

Comment: I tried with org.ops4j.pax.web.ssl.clientauth.needed But Getting error "curl: (58) NSS: client certificate not found (nickname not specified)" but we see osgi pax web documentation has this property named as  org.ops4j.pax.web.ssl.clientauthneeded   , pls suggest why you are asking to use org.ops4j.pax.web.ssl.clientauth.needed

Comment: Updated with list of 3pp bundles we use in the github link you shared. pls check.

Comment: Unfortunately Pax Web documentation is outdated... I didn't have time to update it.

Comment: I have copied 3pp bundle list in the git hub , pls check and also we get error like "curl: (58) NSS: client certificate not found (nickname not specified)" after updated pax web property as you suggested. Any idea?